# Have VS automatically copy DLL to executable output directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I've created an (un-managed) C++ project in VS2013. I've obtained pre-built GLFW binaries for windows, which include files `glfw3dll.lib` and `glfw3.dll`, which are both currently in the same directory. I've added the library and search path to my project options and can successfully build. I can also successfully run if I copy the `glfw3.dll` file to the location of my executable.

How can I tell the VS build system to automatically copy this file? I tried adding it to my project and looking for something under its properties like "copy to output directory" (as exists in .NET projects), but I didn't see anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VS's **post-build event** in order to copy necessary dependencies at the end of the build process. The [TargetDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064(v=vs.85).aspx) property usually specifies by default the destination directory

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you used `xcopy` instead of plain 'ol `copy`?

Comment: You can safely use copy, that screen was from a stripped down version which did additional stuff.